# FB Share popup SHRINKING on Live site

Tags: javascript, php

I use the same FB app for both dev/live. I've made sure fb.js is correct. I just pushed quite a lot of code, fyi. I tested a lot, but you never know. I've never seen anything like this and don't know how to fix.

To see, click the links and try to share on facebook: dev http://dev.disheroo.com/GuestMeal/chicken-puffs-broccoli-sliced-apples/105

live https://www.disheroo.com/GuestMeal/chicken-puffs-broccoli-sliced-apples/105

Comment: Why the downvote?  For not including any code?  I'd like to know for the future.  Constructive criticism welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's facebook bug...
[share dialog is shrinking](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331432664277545/)

Comment: Thank you for this!  I searched and searched and couldn't find anything.  It's nice to know that I didn't do anything wrong :)